# How to convert Time UUID to date time stamp in c#

Tags: c#, cassandra, uuid, timeuuid

I have a `TimeUuid` which I need to convert to a `DateTime`.

Is there a way to do this in C#?

I am using a [CassandraCsharpDriver from DataStax](https://github.com/datastax/csharp-driver), but it does not have the capability to convert the `TimeUuid` to `Datetime`, but the opposite is possible.

Example UUID: `d91027c5-bd42-11e6-90be-2b4914b28d57`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`GetDate()` method](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/csharp/3.1/html/M_Cassandra_TimeUuid_GetDate.htm) of the [`TimeUuid` structure](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/csharp/3.1/html/T_Cassandra_TimeUuid.htm), that returns the `DateTimeOffset` representation of the value.

```
TimeUuid uuidValue = row.GetValue<TimeUuid>("time");
// TimeUuid structure exposes GetDate() method
DateTimeOffset dateOffset = uuidValue.GetDate();
DateTime dateTime = dateOffset.DateTime;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use these 2 helpers and convert to datetime using the **`GetDateTime`** method,

[GuidVersion.cs](https://github.com/fluentcassandra/fluentcassandra/blob/master/src/GuidVersion.cs)

[file-guidgenerator-cs](https://gist.github.com/nberardi/3759706#file-guidgenerator-cs)

**Code:**

```
  String uuidString = "28442f00-2e98-11e2-0000-89a3a6fab5ef";
  Guid gui = new Guid(uuidString);
  DateTime dt = GuidGenerator.GetDateTime(gui);
```

Comment: I think the OP asked about a method to convert a `TimeUuid` into `DateTime` using the DataStax driver, your answer refers to FluentCassandra driver.

Comment: I try to revere `dt` to `uuidString` but got new guid, not like `28442f00-2e98-11e2-0000-89a3a6fab5ef`. what's problem ?